# Using google drive to store data for respective user?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to develop android app something like `"Notes"`. The idea is to ask user to sign in to his google account and use his drive space to store his notes. Simply user should have his data with him & should pay for storage if necessary. Also in future this should work for Windows, iOS.

Till now, I have discovered Drive API and I'm confused. Its is showing 'me' the billing options.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the billing options you see are for your console project. you wont need to enable billing unless you will use up the daily quotas. the free quotas are very large, in the millions of calls per day. those quotas are not related to the space your files will use in each user's drive. they just refer to your right to call the apis with your console keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are seeing billing options, but the Drive API stores items in the user's Drive using the user's quota.